# Do skeletal templates that increase HD beyond 20 prevent that creature from being animated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, undead, necromancy, hit-dice

So assuming our cleric casts desecrate and attempts to reanimate a Storm Giant (19HD) which starts below the 20HD threshold of not being animate-able but adds the skeletal champion template to that (which adds 2 HD making the total 21HD) prevent the Storm Giant from being reanimated as a Storm Giant Skeletal Champion?

Comment: What level is the cleric?

Comment: Our cleric is level 13. So with Desecrate she can create up to and control 52HD worth of undead with animate dead. and then can control up to an additional 13HD worth of undead from Command Undead channel energy ability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Skeletal Champion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeletal-champion-cr-1/) template is a separate and distinct template to the [Skeleton](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeleton) template. It is the Skeleton template that has a maximum of 20 Hit Dice, not the [Animate Dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead) spell or the Skeletal Champion template.

Having said that, without some other ability, I don't see any way to create a Skeletal Champion with Animate Dead, with or without Desecrate? Or any other variant Skeletons other than Burning and Bloody Skeletons, for that matter.

Comment: Well, Animate Dead allows you to create Burning Skeletons and Bloody Skeletons, at the cost of hit dice.

Comment: @goodguy5 OK, missed those. Good catch. (I don't play necromancers, I play heroes! :))

Comment: An animated skeleton is just a grumpy animated object.

Comment: Oh you are totally right, skeletal champion isn't one of the variants that can be used with animate dead. One way the caster can make a skeletal champion is through Create Undead https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead/ . But as it states, it's not automatically under the control of the user. They can use the Command Undead channel energy to try and command it, but that would require the caster to be at the same or higher level than the HD of the skeletal champion. Therefore: can be made, but not controlled.

Comment: One more addendum: the caster must have a higher caster level than the HD of the created undead. Therefore: the caster must have an effective caster level of 21 to do so. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @Thomas Mundane There are ways of artificially increasing caster level, so not even 21 makes it impossible, just difficult without preparation.

Comment: @YogoZuno You are entirely correct, good looking out. Through feat selection and magic items one could raise their caster level to be high enough to make this feasible. That Storm Giant Skeletal Champion shall be mine ;-)